# A robot surviving on top of a 3x3 platform

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

A robot sits in the central square on top of a 3x3 platform. The robot can move up, down, left or right, but if it steps off the platform it will crash and die. You can preprogram the robot to make a sequence of moves, each in one of the four allowed directions. An evil captor can choose to execute your every move, or every second move (starting from second move) or every third move (starting from third move) and so on for any n-th move. So if the programmed move sequence is ABCDEFGH then the evil captor can choose to execute ABCDEFGH, or BDFH or CF or DH. What is the longest sequence of moves you can preprogram for your robot to stay alive no matter what the evil captor does?

Comment: This is very similar to a problem solved by Terence Tao that was posed be Erdős: https://www.wired.com/2015/10/a-magical-answer-to-an-80-year-old-puzzle/

Comment: Yes this is where I got the inspiration from!

Answer (score 24):

I read the [Wired article](https://www.wired.com/2015/10/a-magical-answer-to-an-80-year-old-puzzle/) that was linked in the comments, and applied the ideas mentioned there to this problem, and my computer managed to find a solution that is

> 214 (now improved to 311 moves, see edit below)

moves long, and cannot find a solution of more moves. I do not know if this is an optimal solution.

My solution is:

> UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD RUDL UD LUDR UD LUDDUDRU DLUDUUDR UD LUDR UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD RUDL LDUUDR UD LURD UD RUDL LDUUDR UD LURLRD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD RUDL UD RULRLD LUDDUDRU RL LDUUDR LR LUDDUDRU RL UD DU DRUDLLUURD RUDL UD LUDR DRLU UD LDRU DLUDUUDR RDLL

I've split it by hand into chunks that return the robot to the centre spot, so you can easily check that the robot stays inside the square. If you take every second move, you get:

> DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UD DU LDUR DU RDUL DU RDUUDULD URDUDDUL DU RDUL DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UD DU LDUR RUDDUL DU RDLU DU LDUR RUDDUL DU RDL

and this is

> the original sequence rotated by 180 degrees. This is because my computer program tried to find a multiplicative function $f:N\to Z_4$ where $Z_4$ is the cyclic group of 4 elements, i.e. $\{1, r, r^2, r^3\}$. These four elements represent the four directions U, R, D, L.
>  Multiplicative means that $f(a*b) = f(a)*f(b)$. This is a very nice property here. If you take the subsequence consisting of every $k$th element, then the multiplicative property gives you that $f(k*n)=f(k)*f(n)$, i.e. you get the original sequence multiplied by a constant $f(k)$ which in this context is the original sequence rotated by some amount. This works for every $k$, so as long as the original sequence stays within the bounds, then so does every $k$-subsequence.
>  Essentially the program only chooses which directions to use at the prime-numbered steps. All the other steps are determined through the multiplicative property. The program found 3200 solutions starting with the U move, or 1600 unique solutions and their mirror images.

Regarding possible optimality:

> This is not necessarily optimal. It is the longest solution that has the multiplicative property. It turns out that it can be extended by letting go of the multiplicative property.
>  If I understand the 1-dimensional case in the linked article correctly, it was proven that if there is an infinitely long solution, then there is an infinitely long multiplicative one, so they only needed to prove multiplicative solutions were always finite in order to prove there were no infinitely long solutions. However, this does not rule out there being edge effects in the finite case that allow for longer non-multiplicative solutions.

**EDIT:**
I have now extended the above solution to

> 311 moves.

I did this by a depth first search, starting two moves before the end of the above solution. The new solution is:

> UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD RUDL UD LUDR UD LUDDUDRU DLUDUUDR UD LUDR UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD RUDL LDUUDR UD LURD UD RUDL LDUUDR UD LURLRD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD RUDL UD RULRLD LUDDUDRU RL LDUUDR LR LUDDUDRU RL UD DU DRUDLLUURD RUDL UD LUDR DRLU UD LDRU DLUDUUDR RDUL DRUUDUDL UD DLUR RDLU DU UD RUDL LDUUDR UD LUDDUR RUDL UD ULDR UD DU ULRD URDL RUDULRDDLLRU UD DU LDUDRU DRLRUL DLUR URD

Since this no longer has the nice properties of the previous solution, for each of the $k$-subsequences we need to check that the robot stays within the bounds of the square. Here are the various subsequences:

> 2: DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UD DU LDUR DU RDUL DU RDUUDULD URDUDDUL DU RDUL DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UD DU LDUR RUDDUL DU RDLU DU LDUR RUDDUL DU RDLRUULD LR DU UD ULDURD UD RULD LR DU LDRLUURD LUDUDDUR RL LR R
>  3: RL DRLU RL LR LDRLUR LR RL DRLU RL URLD RL URLLRLDR LURLRRLD RL URLD RL DRLU RL LR LDRLUR URDL DRLU RL URLD RL URDL ULDR LUDDRRUL U
>  4: UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD RUDL UD LUDR UD LUDDUDRU DLUDUUDR UD LUDR UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD RL R
>  5: DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UD DU LDUR DU RDUL DU RDUUDULD URDUDDUL DU RDUL DU LDUR DR
>  6: LR ULRD LR RL RULRDL RL LR ULRD LR DLRU LR DLRRLRUL RDLRLLRU DRL
>  7: UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD RUDL UD LUDR UD LUDDUDUURD LR
>  8: DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UD DU LDUR DU RDUL DU RDUUDL
>  9: DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UD DU LDUR DU UD ULDURL
>  10: UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD RUDL UD LUDR R
>  11: DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UD DU LDUR DLRR
>  12: RL DRLU RL LR LDRLUR LR RL DRLU R
>  13: UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD ULD
>  14: DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UD DU DR
>  15: LR ULRD LR RL RULRDL RL LR
>  16: UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU L
>  17: DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UL
>  18: UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU L
>  19: UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLL
>  20: DU LDUR DU UD ULDUR
>  21: RL DRLU RL LR LDUD
>  22: UD RUDL UD DU DRLR
>  23: DU LDUR DU UD ULD
>  24: LR ULRD LR RL RU
>  25: UD RUDL UD DU DR
>  26: DU LDUR DU UD L
>  27: LR ULRD LR ULR
>  28: UD RUDL UD DU R
>  29: DU LDUR DU UD
>  30: RL DRLU RL LR
>  31: UD RUDL UD DR
>  32: DU LDUR DU U
>  33: LR ULRD LR R
>  34: UD RUDL UD L
>  35: DU LDUR DU
>  36: DU LDUR DU
>  37: UD RUDL UD
>  38: DU LDUR DL
>  39: RL DRLU U
>  40: UD RUDL U
>  41: DU LDUR R
>  42: LR ULRD D
>  43: UD RUDL L
>  44: DU LDUR R
>  45: UD RUDL
>  46: UD RUDL
>  47: DU LDUR
>  48: RL DRLU
>  49: UD RUDD
>  50: DU LDUR
>  51: LR ULRL
>  52: UD RUD
>  53: DU LDU
>  54: RL DRL
>  55: UD RUD
>  56: DU LDU
>  57: RL DRL
>  58: UD RUD
>  59: DU LDU
>  60: LR ULR
>  61: UD RUD
>  62: DU LDR
>  63: DU LD
>  64: UD RU
>  65: DU LD
>  66: RL DR
>  67: UD RU
>  68: DU LD
>  69: LR UL
>  70: UD RU
>  71: DU UD
>  72: UD RU
>  73: UD DU
>  74: DU LD
>  75: RL DR
>  76: UD RL
>  77: DU LR
>  78: LR U
>  79: LR R
>  80: DU L
>  81: UD U
>  82: UD R
>  83: DU L
>  84: RL D
>  85: UD R
>  86: DU L
>  87: LR U
>  88: UD R
>  89: RL D
>  90: DU L
>  91: UD U
>  92: DU L
>  93: RL D
>  94: UD R
>  95: DU L
>  96: LR U
>  97: LR D
>  98: DU D
>  99: UD R
>  100: UD R
>  101: DU U
>  102: RL L
>  103: UD U
>  104: DU
>  105: LR
>  106: UD
>  107: RL
>  108: LR
>  109: RU
>  110: DU
>  111: RL
>  112: UD
>  113: DL
>  114: LR
>  115: UD
>  116: DU
>  117: DU
>  118: UD
>  119: DU
>  120: RL
>  121: UD
>  122: DU
>  123: LR
>  124: UD
>  125: DU
>  126: UD
>  127: UR
>  128: DU
>  129: RL
>  130: UD
>  131: DL
>  132: LR
>  133: UD
>  134: DU
>  135: RL
>  136: UD
>  137: LR
>  138: RL
>  139: LU
>  140: DU
>  141: LR
>  142: UD
>  143: DL
>  144: DU
>  145: UD
>  146: DU
>  147: RD
>  148: UD
>  149: RU
>  150: LR
>  151: LR
>  152: DL
>  153: UL
>  154: UR
>  155: DR

Here is the computer program that I used to find the first solution.

```
 using System;
 namespace test
 {
    class PseRobot
    {
       static int[] moves = new int[215];
       static int[] dirsx = { 0, 1, 0, -1 };
       static int[] dirsy = { 1, 0, -1, 0 };

       static void Main()
       {
          for (int i = 0; i < moves.Length; i++) moves[i] = -1;
          moves[1] = 0;

          Search(1, 0, 0);
       }

       static void Search(int ix, int x, int y)
       {
          if (ix >= moves.Length)
          {
             for(int i=1; i<moves.Length; i++)
             {
                Console.Write("URDL"[moves[i]]);
             }
             Console.WriteLine();
             return;
          }
          if (moves[ix] >= 0)
          {
             int newx = x + dirsx[moves[ix]];
             int newy = y + dirsy[moves[ix]];
             if (Math.Abs(newx) <= 1 && Math.Abs(newy) <= 1)
             {
                Search(ix + 1, newx, newy);
             }
          }
          else
          {
             for (int d = 0; d < 4; d++)
             {
                int newx = x + dirsx[d];
                int newy = y + dirsy[d];
                if (Math.Abs(newx) <= 1 && Math.Abs(newy) <= 1)
                {
                   // mark all multiples that you can already know
                   for (int f = 1, ix2=ix; ix2 < moves.Length; f++, ix2+=ix)
                   {
                      if (moves[f] >= 0) moves[ix2] = (moves[f] + d) % 4;
                   }
                   Search(ix + 1, newx, newy);
                   // unmark all multiples
                   for (int ix2 = ix; ix2 < moves.Length; ix2 += ix)
                   {
                      moves[ix2] = -1;
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Ooh, this can be thought of as a multiplicative sequence over 1, I, -1, -i, and then the position on the platform can be thought of as a position in the complex plane. Did you exhaust the space of multiplicative sequences with your program?

Comment: @isaacg Indeed it can. I did exhaustively search length max+1 to show there were none, but when going through length max I stopped it after the screen rapidly filled up with solutions. There seem to be lots of minor variations with different values at the largest primes. The one I gave was the first one it produced.

Comment: Very nicely done! So would this be the optimal answer?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky If the optimal solution is a multiplicative function, then yes. In the 1-dimensional problem that was apparently proved to be the case, and I would think it is the same here.

Comment: Great work. I'll see if I can find solutions that are not based on such functions. Anyway this is a very good result, perhaps even worthy of publication if you can extend it to larger grids. Terry will be proud.

Comment: This is great! Congrats!

Comment: Actually, my previous comment is wrong. I don't think even in the 1-dimensional problem that multiplicative functions are necessarily optimal. The only thing needed for the proofs in that case is that if there is no infinitely long solution with multiplicative functions, then there are no infinitely long solutions of any kind. It may well be possible to extend a multplicative solution by a few moves.

Comment: Agreed with Dmitry's comment above: what you've done here could well be worthy of publication in a research journal on mathematics or computer science. Prof Tao is a [Stack Exchange user](https://mathoverflow.net/users/766/terry-tao); you might even consider notifying him of this post in case he would be interested in a collaboration!

Comment: Great extension of the solution Jaap! So it turns out that we don't need multiplicative property after all.

Comment: I fixed the error pointed out by @MikePatterson. For some reason I didn't think I needed to check subsequences of length 2. I now found an actual solution of the same length.

Comment: @isaacg , in the following comment of yours, are you referring to his 214 moves solution ? Also can you please explain in simpler terms, what your comment means?  I am trying to understand Jaap's 214 and 311 answers but am unable to understand the logic behind them. This is your comment that I am talking about, "Ooh, this can be thought of as a multiplicative sequence over 1, I, -1, -i, and then the position on the platform can be thought of as a position in the complex plane. Did you exhaust the space of multiplicative sequences with your program?"

Answer (score 12):

I wrote a straightforward depth-first-search program, and found a sequence of length

> 129

namely

> ULDUDRUDULDDURURLLDUDRLURLDDURDLURLURLDRULRDDRLLRLUUDRULRRLDDUURDLULRRLDRLLRLRDLURLURDLURLDDRUURLDDUULRLRRLDRDLUDUUDUDDRUULLDRUDL

This took about five minutes to find. I don't see any obvious pattern to extend this indefinitely. I'll leave the program running, and see what shows up.

Here's the program:

```
translate = {
        (0, 1): "R",
        (1, 0): "U",
        (0, -1): "L",
        (-1, 0): "D",
        }

c = [0]
v = [(1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0), (0, 1)]
m = 0
while c:
    succeed = True
    for div in range(1, len(c)):
        up = 0
        right = 0
        for off in range(len(c)//div):
            up += v[c[off*div+div-1]][0]
            right += v[c[off*div+div-1]][1]
            if up < -1 or up > 1 or right < -1 or right > 1:
                succeed = False
                break
        if not succeed:
            break
    if succeed:
        if len(c) > m:
            m = len(c)
            print(m, ''.join(translate[v[i]] for i in c))
        c.append(0)
    else:
        while c[-1] == 3:
            c.pop()
        c[-1] += 1
```

Comment: Yeah, DFS seems like the way to go - mine was BFS and almost no candidates were ever eliminated. It seems like this problem generates way more solutions than it prunes. +1

Answer (score 5):

Partial:

It's at least

> 28

using

> [image]

I just wrote a program to enumerate them; it's still running. I would hope to find an analytical solution but I figured it would be best to generate some examples first. Obviously any rotations or reflections of this also work. Note that if you are enumerating them, you can reduce the work by quite a lot if you assume the first two commands will be (say) either UR or UD. Any UL strings will have a reflection in UR, and any strings that don't start with U will have a rotation that starts with U.

Edited with better solution. I also changed the pruning a bit - all strings start with U and all strings have L before they have R. I think this eliminates all rotations and reflections. Even without rotations and reflections, there are millions of solutions of this length and the number at each length seems to still be growing steadily.

Note that

> When you are trying to go from length P-1 to length P where P is prime, you always at least double the number of candidates (in reality, it's closer to tripling). This is because when you extend a solution of length P-1, it is only now not a solution if it falls off in the "execute every instruction" case. In all other captor strategies, the new instruction is not executed. No matter where the robot is, there will be either 2, 3, or 4 valid instructions that will keep it on the board.
>
>
>  So far I've only seen three lengths which reduce the number of candidates - 12, 18 and 24. This makes sense, since they have several divisors.

Answer (score 4):

I have a minor correction to Jaap Scherphuis's answer; swapping two pairs of moves makes it valid again.  (I don't have enough reputation to comment.)

Edit: Also, how do I put a large block of text in a scrollable box?

> Jaap's 311 move solution fails for n=149 and n=154, both of which result in the sequence UU.
> By swapping moves 149 and 151, and swapping moves 308 and 309, we have a valid 311 move solution.  I have been unable to find a longer one so far.
> Revised 311 move solution (modified moves are marked with an asterisk):
>
> `1     UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD RUDL UD LUDR UD LUDDUDRU DLUDUUDR UD LUDR UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD RUDL LDUUDR UD LURD UD RUDL LDUUDR UD LURLRD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD RUDL UD RULRLD LUDDUDRU D*LU*DUUDR LR LUDDUDRU RL UD DU DRUDLLUURD RUDL UD LUDR DRLU UD LDRU DLUDUUDR RDUL DRUUDUDL UD DLUR RDLU DU UD RUDL LDUUDR UD LUDDUR RUDL UD ULDR UD DU ULRD URDL RUDULRDDLLRU UD DU LDUDRU DRLRUL DLUR* U*RD
> 2     DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UD DU LDUR DU RDUL DU RDUUDULD URDUDDUL DU RDUL DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UD DU LDUR RUDDUL DU RDLU DU LDUR RUDDUL DU RDLRUULD LR DU UD ULDURD UD RULD LR DU LDRLUURD LUDUDDUR RL LR* R
> 3     RL DRLU RL LR LDRLUR LR RL DRLU RL URLD RL URLLRLDR LURLRRLD RL URLD RL DRLU RL LR LDRLUR URDL DRLU RL URLD RL URDL ULDR LUDDRRUL U*
> 4     UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD RUDL UD LUDR UD LUDDUDRU DLUDUUDR UD LUDR UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD RL R*
> 5     DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UD DU LDUR DU RDUL DU RDUUDULD URDUDDUL DU RDUL DU LDUR DR
> 6     LR ULRD LR RL RULRDL RL LR ULRD LR DLRU LR DLRRLRUL RDLRLLRU DRL
> 7     UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD RUDL UD LUDR UD LUDDUDUURD LR* 
> 8     DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UD DU LDUR DU RDUL DU RDUUDL 
> 9     DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UD DU LDUR DU UD ULDURL
> 10    UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD RUDL UD LUDR R
> 11    DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UD DU LDUR DLRR*
> 12    RL DRLU RL LR LDRLUR LR RL DRLU R
> 13    UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU UD ULD
> 14    DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UD DU DR*
> 15    LR ULRD LR RL RULRDL RL LR 
> 16    UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU DU L
> 17    DU LDUR DU UD ULDURD UL
> 18    UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLU L
> 19    UD RUDL UD DU DRUDLL
> 20    DU LDUR DU UD ULDUR
> 21    RL DRLU RL LR LDUD
> 22    UD RUDL UD DU DRLR*
> 23    DU LDUR DU UD ULD
> 24    LR ULRD LR RL RU
> 25    UD RUDL UD DU DR
> 26    DU LDUR DU UD L
> 27    LR ULRD LR ULR
> 28    UD RUDL UD DU R*
> 29    DU LDUR DU UD 
> 30    RL DRLU RL LR 
> 31    UD RUDL UD DR
> 32    DU LDUR DU U
> 33    LR ULRD LR R
> 34    UD RUDL UD L
> 35    DU LDUR DU 
> 36    DU LDUR DU 
> 37    UD RUDL UD 
> 38    DU LDUR DL
> 39    RL DRLU U
> 40    UD RUDL U
> 41    DU LDUR R
> 42    LR ULRD D
> 43    UD RUDL L
> 44    DU LDUR R*
> 45    UD RUDL 
> 46    UD RUDL 
> 47    DU LDUR 
> 48    RL DRLU 
> 49    UD RUDD
> 50    DU LDUR 
> 51    LR ULRL
> 52    UD RUD
> 53    DU LDU
> 54    RL DRL
> 55    UD RUD
> 56    DU LDU
> 57    RL DRL
> 58    UD RUD
> 59    DU LDU
> 60    LR ULR
> 61    UD RUD
> 62    DU LDR
> 63    DU LD
> 64    UD RU
> 65    DU LD
> 66    RL DR
> 67    UD RU
> 68    DU LD
> 69    LR UL
> 70    UD RU
> 71    DU UD 
> 72    UD RU
> 73    UD DU 
> 74    DU LD
> 75    RL DR
> 76    UD RL 
> 77    DU LR* 
> 78    LR U
> 79    LR R
> 80    DU L
> 81    UD U
> 82    UD R
> 83    DU L
> 84    RL D
> 85    UD R
> 86    DU L
> 87    LR U
> 88    UD R
> 89    RL D
> 90    DU L
> 91    UD U
> 92    DU L
> 93    RL D
> 94    UD R
> 95    DU L
> 96    LR U
> 97    LR D
> 98    DU D
> 99    UD R
> 100   UD R
> 101   DU U
> 102   RL L
> 103   UD U*
> 104   DU 
> 105   LR 
> 106   UD 
> 107   RL 
> 108   LR 
> 109   RU
> 110   DU 
> 111   RL 
> 112   UD 
> 113   DL
> 114   LR 
> 115   UD 
> 116   DU 
> 117   DU 
> 118   UD 
> 119   DU 
> 120   RL 
> 121   UD 
> 122   DU 
> 123   LR 
> 124   UD 
> 125   DU 
> 126   UD 
> 127   UR
> 128   DU 
> 129   RL 
> 130   UD 
> 131   DL
> 132   LR 
> 133   UD 
> 134   DU 
> 135   RL 
> 136   UD 
> 137   LR 
> 138   RL 
> 139   LU
> 140   DU 
> 141   LR 
> 142   UD 
> 143   DL
> 144   DU 
> 145   UD 
> 146   DU 
> 147   RD
> 148   UD 
> 149   D*U 
> 150   LR 
> 151   U*R
> 152   DL
> 153   UL
> 154   UR*
> 155   DR`

I have also been searching for a sequence independently:

> Like others, I have been using a depth-first search.  However, to limit the search space, if both L and R are valid moves I only consider L, and if both U and D are valid moves I only consider U.  This quickly gave me a 174 move solution:
>
> `UD LR LURLDR LDRLUUDURLDR LR RL URDDUDUULLRLDR URLLRRDL ULRRLD RL LUDUDDUR LDRLUR URDL DRLU ULDR ULRD URDL RL DU LURD DRUDLLUURRDL LR LR RDUULD RUDULLDDRRLU RDUUDL ULRD LDRU DRLRUL LR DLUDRU DU UD DLUUDDRRUD`
>
> I then allowed 1 exception to that rule, which yielded a 183 move solution (exception at move 7):
>
> `UD LUDR RL LR LDRLUR LURLDR LURLRRDL UD RULD UD LURRLD RUDL UD RUDL UD LURRDDLU DU LDRU LR UD LUDDUDRLRLRRUUDL UD DU LR UD DU ULDDRU LURD LUDR UD ULDDUR LURRDDUUDL URDULD LDRU RL LDUUDUDDRLRRUL LURD UD DU LUDDUDUR LR DU LURD L`
>
>
> With 2 exceptions, a 239 move solution (exceptions at moves 19 and 47):
>
> `UD LR LURLRRDDUL URDL RL DRLU RL DU LDUDUUDR ULDURRDL LR DLUDRRLU RDLU URDDUULLRD RUDDUDLU LR LDRLRLUR DU LURD LUDR UD DU ULDDRU ULDDUUDR UD UD DLUUDUDDUDUUDR UD RUDL LDRU DU UD LR URDDLU DLUR RUDDUULLDR LDRLRU UD DU UD UD LUDR UD LURLDDRU DU LDUDRRLU DU DLRLUDRRLU DRUL LDUR ULRLRRDDUULRD`
>
> With 3 exceptions, a 245 move solution (exceptions at moves 5, 11, and 25):
>
> `ULDR RUDL UD RDLRLU LDRU UD LR RUDL LURD LR LURLRD LDUURRDL ULRD LURRLRDDUL DU LUDDRU ULRD LR LDRRUUDULLRD UD RL LR URDL RUDL LURRDDUL LDUR DU LR RULLDDRU ULRRLD LR LURLRD ULRRLD DU URDDLU RUDL ULRD URDUDL LR RDUL LR ULDURD DU URLD ULDDUR RUDL UD LUDURRDL UD LDRU LR UD LURRDULLRLDR RDLU UD UD ULDR DU R`
>
> I also performed exhaustive searches starting with certain sequences of moves.  I believe the longest solution that starts with UDULRR is 219:
>
> `UD ULRRLRDL RL LR DU DU LR ULRD URDL DU RDLU DRUDLLUDRRUL DU UD RUDL LR RUDDLU DLRRUDLU ULDDUURD DRUDLU LURLRD LR LURRDDUL RL UD DU LR LR RL RL LDRRUULD DLRU URLLRD DRLU DU URDDUDUL ULDR LR RL DU RULLRD LR RULD RDLLRU LR LDUUDR RL UD LR RL DU URDL ULDR LUDDUR RL RL LDUUDURD R`
>
>
> ...and the longest solution starting with ULDDRRLUUD is 254:
>
> `ULDDRRLU UD RUDULD ULDURD UD DU DRLU RL LR LDRLUR UD DLRRLU RL DRLRUL URLD RL LR LURLDR DU RL URDDUL UD ULDUDR LDRLUR URLLRRDL DLRRUUDL LR LR RL DRUL UD LR DU DLRU URDL LR ULRD RUDDUDLU URDL RULLRD URLLDUDDRRUL LDRRUL RUDULD LR DLUDRRUL LR RULD ULDUDR DU URDL ULRD UD RULRLRDL LURLDDUUDR UD LDUURLDR DU UD DU URDL`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error. For some reason I didn't check subsequences of length 2. I have fixed my answer now.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>  LDRRULRULLDR
>   D R L U L R
>    R  L  L  R
> ```
>
> leaves robots 1, 2 and 3 where they started.

Comment: I probably didn't clarify the problem very well, but the captor can choose any n-th move including n=4. In that case your solution gives RUR which makes the robot fall off. I fixed the problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT :  I found a better solution for

> **17 steps** [image]

Omitting the older solution as that is no more valid